# VB 2010 MS ACCESS datetime

Tags: ms-access

I have used MS Access as my db and vb2010 as front end. Now I am not getting exact datetime value in date_recive column. 
I have set the custom date format in design view of Access table and default value as NOW(). I am getting the correct date value in db after saving the record but not the time.
So can you please suggest me.

Comment: Do not add formats to tables, it is almost ever a good idea.

Comment: Can you clarify what is going on and what is expected? For instance, is the time off by 4 seconds or 2 hours?

Comment: Actually I need date with time when user click on save button. Then in db file data should be saved like dd/mm/yyyy and time as system time in date_receive column. I am getting the correct date but not the time.

Comment: When you say saved, are you adding a new record or updating an old one? Please post some code. Also, please answer @HelloW's question.

Comment: I am adding a new record. When I click on add button it gives me option to enter new record but date field is not coming as blank and it is showing the old date of another record. If i change the date manully still it does not reflect the time in db when I click on save to this new record.

Comment: I just want the date field should come up as blank when I click on add button like other buttons. It shows the value of old records when I click on add. I have set Me.Date_ReceiveDateTimePicker.Value = " "

Answer (score 1):

*I neglected to read the part about VB 2010 this **code only applies to Access VBA***
If you want the save button click event to set the date time field you will need to set it with code.  If your field was named dtmNow and was in the record source for this form, this code will set the field to the current date and time and save the record.

```
Me!dtmNow = Now()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

There may be a problem with this approach because this code will run no matter what you are changing.  This will not reflect the date and time entered but the date and time last saved.